# Making a basic navigation for iOS with two buttons on both sides of the title

Tags: codenameone

I am working on codenameone, and trying to make the first UI.
A basic UI with a title and two buttons on two sides of the "title" to go to two different pages.
I was trying to do that with "Form" component but then it only gives one button by default, which is just taking me to the previous screen.
Not sure how to do this, any link or tip is a nice help.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addCommand(new Command("X"))` or in the GUI builder just click the commands property in the form. It will automatically use the menu for Android.

The back button is added automatically for iOS apps for back navigation which you will probably need. You can disable it in the state machine code and have room for two commands in the title.